# What is $Th(\mathbb{N})$? How to correctly reason about it?

Tags: logic

So I am curious how to correctly reason about $Th(\mathbb{N})$.
Is it a set of constants 0,1 and relations on them?

E.g can we say that $(1+1+1+1) * (1+1+1)$ is in $Th(\mathbb{N})$ because we take a constant $(1+1+1+1) \in \mathbb{N}$ and constant $(1+1+1) \in  \mathbb{N}$ and apply relation $*$ on them that produces new number $n$ such that $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Am I reasoning in a right way?

Can we say that relations $ +, -, *, /, \sqrt{} $ etc are all relations in  $Th(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: As your title asks, "What is $Th(\mathbb{N})$?", it is necessary to answer this part of the Question, defining $Th(\mathbb{N})$, before addressing the part about whether you "correctly reason" about it.  You tagged this "elementary number theory", but it seems that your concerns are about the foundations of mathematics and logic.  If you are interested in formal first-order theories of the natural numbers, you might learn something about that, e.g. Peano's axioms, to make your Question more specific and better grounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$Th(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of sentences in the first-order language of arithmetic (usually understood to be $\{+, \times, 0, 1\}$) which are true of the natural numbers.

So, for example:

- "$\forall x(x=0)$" is not in $Th(\mathbb{N})$, because it is not true that every natural number is zero.
- "$1+1=2$" is not in $Th(\mathbb{N})$, because there is no primitive symbol for "2".
- "$1+1+1$" is not in $Th(\mathbb{N})$, because it is a *term*, not a *sentence* - what would it mean for "$1+1+1$" to be false?
- "$\forall X\subseteq\mathbb{N}(0\in X\implies 0\not\in X)$" is not in $Th(\mathbb{N})$, since in first-order logic we can't quantify over sets.
- But "$\forall x\forall y(x+y=y+x)$ *is* in $Th(\mathbb{N})$. It is a first-order sentence, using only (nonlogical) symbols from among $\{0, 1, +, \times\}$, which is true of $\mathbb{N}$.

---

EDIT: in first order logic, in addition to the *nonlogical symbols* provided by the specific context we're working in (in this case, $+, \times, 0, 1$), we always have: parentheses $(, )$, Boolean connectives $\wedge, \vee, \neg, \implies$, quantifiers $\forall,\exists$, variables $x_0, x_1, . . .$, and equality $=$.

Comment: The 1st and 5th bullets should be problematic for the same reason as the 4th bullet, correct? That is, $x$ and $y$ are sets (all variables in set theory represent sets) and first-order logic doesn't have quantification.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree No, that's not correct - first-order logic does have quantification. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic. I think you are thinking of *propositional* logic, which indeed does not allow quantifiers (but also doesn't allow nonlogical symbols like "$+$" and "$\times$," etc.).

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was mistakenly thinking of propositional logic.

Comment: So x and y may be only 0 or 1?

Comment: @YanyongXu No, the variables may refer to anything, but we only have specific names for 0 and 1. Think about it this way: suppose I only knew two people, named Sam and Alex. Then I might know "there are people other than Sam and Alex," but I wouldn't know any specific people other than Sam and Alex - I might not even know any *names* other than "Sam" and "Alex"! So I could still say things like, "Every person has a head," and this statement would be true even of people like Morgan (who I don't know), but I couldn't say "Morgan has a head" because I don't know the name "Morgan."

Comment: how do I know my $\Bbb N$ has the same theory as your $\Bbb N$ ?

Comment: Okay. But can I say that $(1+1+1) \times (1+1+1+1) \in Th(\mathbb N)$?

Comment: @mercio For the moment I'm taking as granted that there is a "real" object $\mathbb{N}$ that we're talking about. If you want to get into philosophical issues around how we individually think about the natural numbers, there's lots of great stuff there, but I don't think this question is a good place to get into that.

Comment: @YanyongXu Well, you can't say that exact string in the language of arithmetic - what are "$\in$" and "$\mathbb{N}$"? However, in first-order logic we always assume that terms *refer* to things - that is, we don't allow undefined terms. So, since we can form the term $(1+1+1)\times (1+1+1+1)$, then yes, we can use this to refer directly to the number 12 even though we don't have a specific name "12" (similarly to how I can refer to "Sam's best friend" without knowing Sam's best friend's name - I've *uniquely specified* a person, and that's good enough).

Comment: @YanyongXu (cont'd) Now, $\mathbb{N}$ has a remarkable property - as long as I have symbols for $0, 1,$ and $+$, I can refer uniquely to every natural number! That is, every natural number corresponds to a *closed term* ("closed" just means "no variables"). So in practice I don't have to pay attention to what names for numbers I use. But this is a special feature of $\mathbb{N}$ which is not true of all, or even most, natural mathematical structures. For instance, in the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +, \times, 0, 1)$, how would you name $\pi$?

Comment: @YanyongXu It looks like I misread your most recent comment. No, $(1+1+1)\times (1+1+1+1)$ is not in $Th(\mathbb{N})$ (I read ". . .$\in\mathbb{N}$" instead of ". . . $\in Th(\mathbb{N})$"), since - as I explain in my answer - $(1+1+1)\times (1+1+1+1)$ is not a *statement*. What would it mean for it to be "true" or "false"?

Answer (score 3):

We have to start with a *language* $\mathcal L$, e.g the *first-order* language for *arithmetic* (or *elemntary number theory*) :

> Constant symbols: $0$
>
> One-place function symbols: $S$ (for *successor*)
>
> Two-place function symbols: $+$ (for *addition*) and $\times$ (for *multiplication*).

Then we have to consider a *structure* $\mathcal N =(\mathbb N, 0, S, +, \times)$ for that language.

Finally, we define the *theory* of $\mathcal N$, written $\mathsf {Th} \mathcal N$, as the set of all sentences true in $\mathcal N$.

*Examples* : $0=0 \in \mathsf {Th} \mathcal N$; $\exists n (S(n) = 0) \notin \mathsf {Th} \mathcal N$ (recall that $\mathsf {Th} \mathcal N$ is a set of *sentences*).

The first sentence is clearly true, while the second one is false ($0$ is not a successor).

But we have to pay attention to the language : we can take into account the expessive capability of it.

We cannot say, e.g. : $\exists n (n= \sqrt 4)$ but we can say : $\exists n (n \times n = S(S(S(S(0)))))$.

We cannot say : $0 < 2$ but we have to say : $\exists n (0+n = S(S(0)))$.

In order to use the "usual" expressions, we have to "enlarge" the original language adding suitable definition for the new *terms* and *relations*.

Comment: So $\mathsf {Th} \mathcal N$ has ONLY function symbols $+$ and $\times$ ? Can I say that $(1+1+1) \times (1+1+1+1) \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @YanyongXu - after we have expanded the language with the definition : $1=S(0)$, we can use it. In alternative, see answer above, we can put it into the language from the start. The language has symbols; $\mathsf {Th} \mathcal N$ has sentences, like (after the introduction of $1$) $1+1+1=S(S(S(0)))$. Your example is not a sentence.

Comment: @YanyongXu Note that the language Mauro uses is different from the one I use. Technically, writing "$Th(\mathbb{N})$" is ambiguous - you need to specify exactly what the language is. In practice, though, it rarely matters which of the many natural languages for arithmetic one uses.